# ibtool not parsing iOS .strings file

Tags: ios, ibtool

When loading my .strings file for localization via this command: `--strings-file ja.lproj/localizable.strings en.lproj/AdvancedSearchView.xib --write ja.lproj/AdvancedSearchView.xib` I continually get this error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.ibtool.errors</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>description</key>
            <string>The strings file "localizable.strings" could not be applied.</string>
            <key>recovery-suggestion</key>
            <string>The stringsfile localizable.strings could not be parsed.</string>
            <key>underlying-errors</key>
            <array>
                <dict>
                    <key>description</key>
                    <string>The strings file "localizable.strings" could not be applied.</string>
                    <key>recovery-suggestion</key>
                    <string>The stringsfile localizable.strings could not be parsed.</string>
                </dict>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

However, when I load my file into plutil via `plutil -p ja.lproj/localizable.strings` the strings file parses correctly. Any help as to have ibtool parse the file correctly would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It use to be the case that the file had to use the UTF-16 encoding (or it was highly recommended). Do a "file" on other such files and see if this one is different.

Comment: The file is UTF-16 encoded. No .strings file is working for my ibtool

Comment: Create a demo app, create a strings file, and copy them over one at a time, and verify that each works. At some point you will find the problem. Its a PITA when you don't get an explicit error with a specific line number...I'm dealing with this right now all day...